# After QMediaPlayer seek/setPosition no more screen updates for QGraphicsVideoItem

Tags: qt, video, youtube, qmediaplayer

I got QT5.6 example "videoplayer". It works with local files.
I modify "Open file" function to use internet URL instead of local file. In fact i use youtube URL. Like this:

```
void VideoPlayer::openFile()
{
//QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open Movie"),QDir::homePath());
QString fileName = "https://r4---sn-n8v7znls.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?initcwndbps=1427500&dur=3369.354&sver=3&sparams=dur%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpl%2Cratebypass%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&lmt=1416581653227418&requiressl=yes&ip=80.68.2.81&mime=video%2Fmp4&source=youtube&mm=31&mn=sn-n8v7znls&pl=23&id=o-AODorl7SvqZSnDSvxck5hqt4t3DHXmuquI-oLniRvtIu&ms=au&mt=1464897333&mv=m&expire=1464919182&upn=vf3wyJFr-XM&key=yt6&ipbits=0&ratebypass=yes&itag=18&fexp=9412859%2C9414702%2C9416126%2C9416891%2C9419451%2C9422596%2C9423965%2C9425351%2C9426985%2C9428398%2C9431012%2C9432822%2C9433096%2C9433221%2C9433946%2C9434790%2C9435527%2C9435876%2C9436917%2C9437067%2C9437180%2C9437553&signature=A22462E28C81BAFEA1D411B53F4AA7624179608D.BB0B47C09F09A93C3751D49EEE61AF6059A635FB";
if (!fileName.isEmpty()) {
    mediaPlayer.setMedia(QUrl(fileName));
    playButton->setEnabled(true);
    mediaPlayer.play();
    qDebug() << "playback started!!";
}
```

}

Application starts normally and can play video, BUT!
When i use long video, I do seek position forward and after that no more screen updates for video. Vedio frames are not rendered.

This QT example demonstrates QGraphicsVideoItem on QGraphicsScene - I need both of them in my app. But what to do with seek position? It does not work properly for http URL videos! Besides that mediaPlayer::isSeekable() returns "true".
After seek position player behaves like it really plays from new position point because notification signals like positionChanged() are called periodically . QMediaStatus is QMediaPlayer::BufferedMedia. But no screen updates!

I have a position handler:

```
void VideoPlayer::positionChanged(qint64 position)
{
positionSlider->setValue(position);
qDebug()
        << " pos " << position
        << " sta " << mediaPlayer.mediaStatus();
}
```

After user do seek position i see debug output:

```
pos  2363199  sta  QMediaPlayer::BufferedMedia
pos  2364049  sta  QMediaPlayer::BufferedMedia
pos  2364049  sta  QMediaPlayer::BufferedMedia
pos  2365050  sta  QMediaPlayer::BufferedMedia
pos  2365983  sta  QMediaPlayer::BufferedMedia
pos  2365983  sta  QMediaPlayer::BufferedMedia
```

Seem it plays? but no video output, no audio output.. nothing.
How to handle seek/setPosition for QMediaPlayer in case of internet mp4 URL source?